# dplyr mutate_if with multiple conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that looks as the following:

```
dt <- data.frame(id = sample(LETTERS, 100) ,A = seq(1:100), B = sample(1:100000, 100), C = rpois(100,1), D = seq(1:100)^3)
```

I am trying to transform any variable that has a `max value > 1000`

```
dt %>% mutate_if(max(.) > 1000, log10)
```

For model fitting. But I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in tbl_if_vars(.tbl, .p, .env, ..., .include_group_vars = .include_group_vars) : 
  length(.p) == length(tibble_vars) is not TRUE
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a formula argument

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% mutate_if(~is.numeric(.) && max(., na.rm = TRUE) > 1000, log10)
```

To make it more clear you can use an anonymous function call

```
dt %>% mutate_if(function(x) is.numeric(x) && max(x, na.rm = TRUE) > 1000, log10)
```

Comment: It's not working. I keep getting the following error: "Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols"

Comment: Also, I added another column

Comment: @akash87 To make it work only for numeric columns you can do `dt %>% mutate_if(~is.numeric(.) && max(.) > 1000, log10)` However, I don't get the error message that you receive. Are you using the same dataset shared in the post.

Comment: Still getting the "Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols"

Comment: @akash87 are you using the same dataset as shared in the post?

Comment: No I am not, I am using a simulated dataset

Comment: Does the above answer work on the data you have shared in the post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203944/discussion-between-akash87-and-ronak-shah).